# How to apply two different style properties to the same element in different places?

Tags: html, css

for example I have form element in multiple places like

```
form {
display: table;
margin: 20px auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Now this style properties are overriding another form element's style properties, now form does not have id attribute , I gave the form a name & tried with name attribute but it is not working.

```
form[name="myform"] {
display: table;
margin: 20px auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Please suggest a solution

Comment: All else being equal, there's no reason that wouldn't work (although you shouldn't be using the name attribute on form elements since HTML 4 became a standard (in 1998)). You should provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

assign classes to your form tag, like:

```
<form class="x"> ... </form>
```

and set up CSS for those classes:

```
.x {
  color: red;
  ...
}
```

Concerning question in comment: Here is an example that demonstrates that this works (note the class color overriding the form color):

```css
form { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
  color: blue;
}
.x { color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" class="x">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Jane"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Doe"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can form have id attribute?

Comment: yeah removed i am sorry

Comment: @Johannes — How does using a class instead of a name fix the problem?

Comment: please see the example I added

Comment: @Johannes — While that example demonstrates that it works … [this example](http://jsbin.com/vonaxa/1/edit?html,css,output) shows that the original code in the question works … so how does your approach fix the problem?

Comment: it uses a different approach

Comment: @Quentin why do you downvote answers that provide a working solution?

Comment: @Johannes — It's different yes … but how does it fix the problem? The question fails to demonstrate the problem (which could be caused by anything from a typo to a specificity issue), so it can't be reasonably answered in its current state.

Comment: @Johannes  — It can't be a solution without a problem to solve. It is just some working code.

Comment: @Quentin if one approach doesn't work, you can try another approach. If that works, fine. That's how it's very often done in real life...

Comment: @Johannes —Changing random things in the hope that they will solve the problem is a debugging technique, but a very poor one compared to understanding a problem and solving it using an understanding of how the languages involved work. If the question demonstrated a problem, then you could use that debugging technique to search for an answer. You need to be able to reproduce the problem first though.

Comment: @Quentin I would rather call your downvoting random

Comment: @Johannes — You can divorce yourself from reality as much as you like.

Comment: @Quentin you are not the one who asked, so why do you get all upset? Any way, have a nice day!

Comment: @Johannes — Who said I was upset? You seem to be trying to dismiss my argument by claiming that I'm just being emotional.

Comment: @LJ — The reputation implications for upvotes and downvotes are not equal. An upvote does more than cancel out the downvote, and you've agreed that this doesn't address the problem, so why reward it?

Comment: @LJ — "which will work" — How will it work in the context of the OP's non-working code which we can't see? Will it fix a typo? Only as a (long-winded) side effect of deleting existing code and typing new code. Will it fix a specificity issue? No, there's no change in specificity between the OP's code and this answer's code. Will it fix some other problem I haven't thought of? Who knows? Stackoverflow would be better if people focused on rewarding quality instead of effort.

Comment: BTW: The question header is "How to apply two different style properties to the same element in different places?" - *that* question/problem is answered/solved by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices, but a simple way is to use different `ID`s or different classes like below:

```
<form id="first"> </form>
<form id="second"> </form>
```

Comment: @Quentin can form also have class attribute ?

Comment: @mcl — Seriously? Did you even look at the link I provided in my last comment? (You still haven't provided a [mcve] in the question either)

Comment: Did u find the solution @mcl

Answer (score 0):

- For each page use **another CSS style** with new define element.
- OR Use **Class** like `class="form_1"`
- OR Use **ID** like `id="form_1"`
- OR For **no rewrite** use like `font-size: 18px !important`